Continuity of Fourier Transform of a function of Fourier Coefficients
Suppose that:

I have a a periodic function $u(t)=u(t+2\pi)$ that can be represented by a vector of Fourier coefficients $\tilde{U}=[U_0,\,U_1,\,\dots,U_H]^T$.
I have a continuous function $f(u)$ whose derivatives $df/du$ are only piece-wise continuous.
I denote the Fourier coefficients of $f(u)$ for given $\tilde{U}$ as $\tilde{F}=[F_0,\,F_1,\,\dots,F_H]^T$ such that $F_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f\circ u)(t) e^{-jnt} dt $. I assume that the Fourier integral exists and all the necessary conditions for this hold.
I represent the Fourier coefficients $\tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{F}$ as fully real vectors $\tilde{U}^\prime=[\Re\{\tilde{U}\}^T,\,\Im\{\tilde{U}\}^T]^T$ and $\tilde{F}^\prime=[\Re\{\tilde{F}\}^T,\,\Im\{\tilde{F}\}^T]^T$ respectively.

I am interested in what can be said about the mapping $\tilde{F}^\prime(\tilde{U}^\prime)$. I understand, for instance, that $\tilde{F}(\tilde{U})$ is not complex-differentiable in the general case (this can be seen even for the case of $f(u)=u^3$). But $\tilde{F}^\prime(\tilde{U}^\prime)$ is differentiable since it is a real-valued vector function of vector arguments.
I am specifically interested to know if $\tilde{F}^\prime(\tilde{U}^\prime)$ is continuously differentiable even if $f(u)$ is only continuous (or, more generally, non-smooth).
My intuition is that $\tilde{F}^\prime(\tilde{U}^\prime)$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable) since $df/du$ has discontinuities on measure-zero points only.
I apologize for my lack of rigour in the above - I'm an engineer in a hurry atm, but I'm happy to learn! (:
